# Update column value in multiple rows (more than 100) depending on PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a column value date to Today-1 in many rows depending on the PK value. I know that this will be the correct query (close to correct one at least):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET dateColumn = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
WHERE Id IN (value1, ..., valueN)
```

This is OK when there are 5 or 10 values to depend on. But what if I have 100 of values? Putting them all in `IN` clause is not a great idea I guess. Is there another way?

Comment: It depends on how those values are generated. You may wish to pass a table of values (UDT) from the frontend

Comment: I have used it up to 100.000 values, and it works.

Comment: @Serg those values are totally random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to add them to the `IN` clause:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET dateColumn = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
   WHERE Id IN (value1, ..., valueN);
```

There are other methods.  You could, for instance, use `VALUES()` with a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET dateColumn = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
   FROM (VALUES (value1), ..., (valueN)) v(id)
   WHERE v.id = myTable.id;
```

But I don't really see an advantage to that.

You can also store the values in a temporary table or table variable.  If the table has a primary key on `id`, then this might help performance.

SQL Server does not have an explicit limit (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)).  [But it does warn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15):

> Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632.

A few hundred should not pose a problem.